# UDP server issues with multi ports connections

Tags: go, networking, udp

I have a UDP server that expose two ports, 8080 for normal data and 8082 for controll (keep alive signal). When I start the server one new instance of Server is created. It have a list of clients: a client is represented by a `struct that` contains two types of `UDPConn`, one for control and one for data. What is happening is when I run my `Client.go` I connect to server in both ports but, the server creates two clients instead of only one. Downward are part of my `Server.go` and `Client.go`. What can I do to create only one user for both connections?

Server.go

```golang
func main() {
    server := NewLobby()

    addressCntrl, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(CONN_TYPE, CONN_CNTRL_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error resolving controller address: %s", err)
    }

    listenerCntrl, err := net.ListenUDP(CONN_TYPE, addressCntrl)
    defer listenerCntrl.Close()

    log.Printf("Listening controll on port %s", CONN_CNTRL_PORT)

    addressData, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(CONN_TYPE, CONN_DATA_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error Resolving data address: %s", err)
    }

    listenerData, err := net.ListenUDP(CONN_TYPE, addressData)
    defer listenerData.Close()

    log.Printf("Listening data on port %s", CONN_DATA_PORT)

    for {
        buffer = make([]byte, 1024)
        listenerData.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        c := NewClient(*listenerData, *listenerCntrl)
        server.Join(c)
    }
}
```

NewServer (server.go)

```golang
func NewServer() *Server {
    server := &Server{
        clients:   make([]*Client, 0),
        chatRooms: make(map[string]*ChatRoom),
        incoming:  make(chan *Message),
        join:      make(chan *Client),
        leave:     make(chan *Client),
        delete:    make(chan *ChatRoom),
    }
    server.Listen()
    return server
}
```

NewClient (server.go)

```golang
func NewClient(connData net.UDPConn, connCntrl net.UDPConn) *Client {
    writerData := bufio.NewWriter(&connData)
    readerData := bufio.NewReader(&connData)

    writerCntrl := bufio.NewWriter(&connCntrl)
    readerCntrl := bufio.NewReader(&connCntrl)

    client := &Client{
        name:        CLIENT_NAME,
        chatRoom:    nil,
        incoming:    make(chan *Message),
        outgoing:    make(chan string),
        connData:    connData,
        connCntrl:   connCntrl,
        readerData:  readerData,
        writerData:  writerData,
        readerCntrl: readerCntrl,
        writerCntrl: writerCntrl,
    }

    log.Printf("New client connected")

    client.Listen()
    return client
}
```

Client.go

```golang
func main() {
    server := NewServer()

    addressCntrl, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(CONN_TYPE, CONN_CNTRL_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error resolving controller address: %s", err)
    }

    listenerCntrl, err := net.ListenUDP(CONN_TYPE, addressCntrl)
    defer listenerCntrl.Close()

    log.Printf("Listening controll on port %s", CONN_CNTRL_PORT)

    addressData, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr(CONN_TYPE, CONN_DATA_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error Resolving data address: %s", err)
    }

    listenerData, err := net.ListenUDP(CONN_TYPE, addressData)
    defer listenerData.Close()

    log.Printf("Listening data on port %s", CONN_DATA_PORT)

    for {
        buffer = make([]byte, 1024)
        listenerData.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        c := NewClient(*listenerData, *listenerCntrl)
        server.Join(c)
    }
}
```

One example of output is bellow

Server output

```
2021/05/06 20:03:52 Listening controll on port :8082
2021/05/06 20:03:52 Listening data on port :8080
2021/05/06 20:03:56 New client connected
2021/05/06 20:03:58 New client connected
```

Client output

```
Welcome to the server! Type "/help" to get a list of commands.
Welcome to the server! Type "/help" to get a list of commands.
```

If needed my functions `Read()` and `Write()` of client is bellow.

Read (client.go)

```golang
func Read(connData net.UDPConn, connCntrl net.UDPConn) {
    //Controller
    go func() {
        readerCntrl := bufio.NewReader(&connCntrl)
        for {
            str, _ := readerCntrl.ReadString('\n')
            if strings.Compare(str, "timeout") == 0 {
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        }
    }()

    //Data
    reader := bufio.NewReader(&connData)
    for {
        str, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf(MSG_DISCONNECT)
            wg.Done()
            return
        }
        fmt.Print(str)
    }
}
```

Write (client.go)

```golang
func Write(connData net.UDPConn, connCntrl net.UDPConn) {
    //Controller
    go func() {
        writerCntrl := bufio.NewWriter(&connCntrl)
        for range time.Tick(10 * time.Second) {
            writerCntrl.WriteString("ka")
        }
    }()

    //Data
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    writerData := bufio.NewWriter(&connData)
    for {
        input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error reading input: %s", err)
        }

        _, err = writerData.WriteString(input)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error writing input to server: %s", err)
        }

        err = writerData.Flush()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error flushing the input: %s", err)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit confusion here, where are the read write functions being used in client? Also, can you put shoe the `NewServer` and `NewLobby` functions?

Comment: And also, please check if you have shown correct code for client.go here. Looks like your client is creating one more UDP server insted of connecting to the server.

Comment: @advayrajhansa I made the changes, look if it is more understandable